# JOOQ for SQL query writing: Stack overflow exception in tests

Tags: java, sql, exception, stack-overflow, jooq

The same code works of JOOQ inside psvm but not inside junit tests.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  InsertSetMoreStep<Record> query = DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL)
                                     .insertInto(table("TABLE_NAME"))
                                     .set(field("FIELD"), "field");
  System.out.println("query : " + query.getSQL());
}


@Test
public void tt() {
  InsertSetMoreStep<Record> query = DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL)
                                     .insertInto(table("TABLE_NAME"))
                                     .set(field("FIELD"), "field");
  System.out.println("query : " + query.getSQL());
}
```

Running the test gives the stack over flow exception:

```
LClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

What is the reason and how to fix the test?

Comment: You didn't include the whole exception trace. There are lines missing from before where you copied. Please include the whole thing.

Comment: before that the trace contains the line of program... which has InsertSetMoreStep<Record> query..

Comment: How do you run those unit tests to produce the stack overflow? The code runs just fine in an "ordinary" run configuration.

Comment: my friends on windows and mac are also not facing this issue.. m on Ubuntu 12 and java 8..

Answer (score 0):

This might actually be a real stackoverflow. In this case you can fix it by increasing the stack size with the parameter:

```
-Xss4m
```

Try of an explanation: JOOQ generates java classes from database structure as much as I understand. If JOOQ creates a lot of nested classes, which is very well possible for some database designs, the classloader loads those inner classes recursively which might end in a stack overflow because it's resource intense.

I don't really know JOOQ and I can't reproduce it but it would be nice to see a real stackoverflow :-)

Comment: why do you is the difference in the behavior? it runs fine in psvm. Also the code is only for query writing.. and does not require db schema to exist. you should be able to run in isolation.

Comment: If it's how I described, the difference can be explained that the JVM which runs the server has different stack setting then the JVM that runs the tests.